# Parsing simple json to spinner entries

Tags: java, android, json

I've been trying to get into android/java programming and I've been having issues understanding how to properly get the value of this json and parse it into the options to select in a spinner.

My json is like:

```
["Result1","Result2","Result3"]
```

My current code is like:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://example.com/jsonfile.json";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //Do something with response
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println(error.toString());
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

What would be the easiest way to get these values (Result1, Result2, Result3, etc.) into the spinner.entries?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myString.replace("\"]","");
myString.replace("[\"","");

List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\",\"")));


ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(varRoot, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myList);

spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down vieww

mySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: I had to make a few changes so it wouldn't have a " on the first and last record, but this did it for me.

Comment: Oh yeah I just realised the first two lines wouldn't work (now edited for anyone else looking at this), but glad you worked it out! :)

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge you are sending json data in the wrong way.
If you want to send an array you have to place a jsonArray object in response with name to access that jsonArray.

**Example**

"cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]

Here, we are sending 3 car name in JsonArray of name "cars".

For accessing those entries:-

```
for (i in myObj.cars) {

    carsArray += myObj.cars[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an assync call to get json data. Please refer the following tutorial
[Android assync task example](http://codesfor.in/android-assynctask-example/)
and for parsing json data use [Android json parsing example](http://codesfor.in/android-json-parsing-example/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        //Do something with response
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            array.put(jsonArray.getString(i)); 
        }
    }
```

add this on your activity's OnCreate() metod

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, array, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and put it

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: "Wrong 2nd argument type. Found 'java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>', required 'int'"

What am I doing wrong? Should I use a different version of ArrayList<>?

(Error on ArrayAdapter.createFromResource)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try this if it may help

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    Button btnCall;
    final List<String> reviewList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String>resultList=new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnCall=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
        final String jArrStr="[\"Result1\",\"Result2\",\"Result3\"]";

        btnCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jArry=new JSONArray(jArrStr);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArry.length(); i++) {
                        String strArr=jArry.getString(0);
                        resultList.add(jArry.getString(i));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }



}
```